# Swift function that removes Beacons that are "unknown" - ibeacon

Tags: swift, ibeacon

```
func filteredBeacons(_ beacons: [CLBeacon]) -> [CLBeacon] {
    var filteredBeacons = beacons   // Copy

    var lookup = Set<String>()
    for index in 0..<beacons.count {


        let currentBeacon = beacons[index]
        let identifier = "\(currentBeacon.major)/\(currentBeacon.minor)"

        if lookup.contains(identifier) {
            filteredBeacons.remove(at: index)
        } else {
            lookup.insert(identifier)
        }

    }

    return filteredBeacons
}
```

My understanding is that this code will remove any beacons that are duplicated.  I now want this code to also remove beacons with proximity  "unknown" (i.e. very far away).  Could someone show me how to do this?  I know class CLProximity would be needed.

I am very new to xcode, so would appreciate more explanation if possible.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
func filteredBeacons(_ beacons: [CLBeacon]) -> [CLBeacon] {
    var filteredBeacons = beacons   // Copy

    var lookup = Set<String>()
    for index in 0..<beacons.count {    
        let currentBeacon = beacons[index]
        if currentBeacon.proximity == .unknown {
          filteredBeacons.remove(at: index)
        }
        else {
          let identifier = "\(currentBeacon.major)/\(currentBeacon.minor)"

          if lookup.contains(identifier) {
              filteredBeacons.remove(at: index)
          } else {
              lookup.insert(identifier)
          }
        }
    }

    return filteredBeacons
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works, however, when I run it in the app, the app crashes.  I am not sure why discarding unknowns would result in a crash.  Any ideas on how to fix this?  (Sorry, I lost the log so couldn't find the error message)

Comment: It may crash if you remove two beacons in one pass through the loop, because the index may beyond the length of the array of filteredBeacons

Comment: thanks - does that mean I should create two loops ?  One for removing unknown beacons, and one for removing duplicated beacons?

Comment: I would simply reverse the logic.  Initialize filteredBeacons to an empty array and add a beacon to it if the lookup does not contain the identifier.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to Swift.  Could you explain a bit more on how to  Initialize filteredBeacons to an empty array?

Comment: `var filteredBeacons: [CLBeacon] = []`

Answer (score 1):

To remove any beacon that has proximity `unknown` you just need to add the following snippet in your loop:

```
if currentBeacon.proximity == .unknown {
   filteredBeacons.remove(at: index)
}
```

Btw `CLProximity` is an enum therefore you can just write `.unknown` instead of `CLProximity.unknown`